# how to submit a form after jquery dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation, jquery-dialog

I have a mvc4 web application a page with form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>News</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.summery)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.summery)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.summery)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

I want after form is valid to call a function that will show a confirm dialog (jquery)

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        title: title, closeOnEscape: false,
        buttons: {
            "OK submit": function () {

            },
            "Cancel Submit": function () {

            }
        }
    });
```

what is the best whay to do so ? 
I want the form to be validated ,next step if valid to show confirm message ,next step if "OK submit" 
pressed to submit the form.

Comment: you can also try to call a another view in your controler for display this dialog-message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(formSelector).submit(function(){
   var frm = $(this);
  if (frm.validate()) {
  $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        buttons: {
        "OK submit": function () {
              //not sure - here can be a mistake
              frm.unbind('submit');
             frm.sumbit();

        },
        "Cancel Submit": function () {

        }
    }
 });
 }
 return false;

});
```

If you want to show not a custom dialog you can use this:

```
 $(formSelector).submit(function(){
  var frm = $(this);
  if (frm.validate()) {
          return confirm("Want to submit?");
     }
  return false;
 });
```

Comment: well it looks like it gonna work,but how did it come to be so complicated to do such easy flow :) ? I will try it.

Comment: It's not complicated. Just a few simple steps to add custom behaviour. Also see edits i've added.